# sups and infs of a subset

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \neq \emptyset, A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ bounded set. Show that $\sup{A} \leq \sup{B}$ and $\inf{B} \leq \inf{A}$.

How to prove this obvious statement?

Comment: An upper bound of $B$ is also an upper bound of $A$. Work from there.

Comment: If it's obvious, all you have to do is articulate your reasons for thinking that it is obvious. Job done!

Comment: Hahaha. If I am adult mathematician and can say it's obvious without proving it, but in the role of a mathematics student I have to prove this untill it's *really* obvious.

Answer (score 1):

For the case when $A=B$. $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$ is quite straightforward from the definition.

Now we can discuss $A\subset B$. 
Let $\alpha=\sup(A)$ and $\beta=\sup(B).$ Both $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$. Since $A\subset B\subset \Bbb R.$

Proof:
We can **assume the existence of $A,B$ Such that $\beta\lt\alpha$**. And try to **show contradiction** later.
$\forall a\in A.a\in B.$ following from one being a subset of another. Implies $\beta$ to be an upperbound of $A$.
Since $\alpha$ Is also an upperbound of $A$ and $\beta\lt\alpha$. This **contradict** the prior of $\alpha=\sup(A).$
So there isn’t such sets $A,B$ Where $A\subset B\subset\Bbb R$ That $\sup(A)\gt\sup(B).$  
$\square$

Similar approach can prove the second part of your question :)

To deal with questions like this, I would usually just write out the definitions and think about how the constrains affect the statements? how I could paraphrase the question to something I’m more familiar with? (e.g. I rewrote “$B\subseteq\Bbb R$ And $B$ is bounded”, into “$B\subset \Bbb R$”. Since one implies another, and it make things easier to read.)

Comment: Thanks. Am I bad mathematician if I can't prove this (to me) honestly obvious statements?

Comment: @Learner. It’s ok, just take your time. There are a few books and resources about proofs that may help you. [https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/readings/] (The early part of this course talkes about proofs) which may be helpful. I learned about proofs from Terence Tao’s Analysis, perhaps you could give it a try.